# ArrayFire.jl setindex! very slow

Tags: performance, gpu, julia, gpgpu, arrayfire

So I'm trying to speed up some Julia code using ArrayFire.jl, but instead all I'm doing is slowing it down.  Using `@profile`, I've tracked the problem down to `setindex!`.  Here is the test code:

```
using ArrayFire

function f(x::Array{Float32})
    y = zeros(Float32, size(x))
    for i in 1:length(x)
        y[i] = x[i]
    end
    return y
end

function f(x::AFArray{Float32})
    y = AFArray(zeros(Float32, size(x)))
    for i in 1:length(x)
        y[i] = x[i]
    end
    return y
end

srand(1)

a = rand(Float32, 20, 20)
b = AFArray(a)

@time f(a)
@time f(b)
```

The speed difference between these two is *five* orders of magnitude.

According to the profiler, the reason `setindex!` is really slow is because `af_assign_gen` and `af_sum_all` are really slow.

Am I missing something?  I'm a complete newbie to GPGPU programming, so it's possible I simply am not understanding how this is all supposed to work.

Comment: The `for` loop doesn't run on the GPU, so there is both a synchronization step and a relatively expensive CPU->GPU memory write every iteration. You will really only see a performance boost if you use the array-wise functions listed in "Supported Functions", not for arbitrary Julia code. (Also,  be sure to read the "Note on REPL behavior" and "A note on benchmarking" in the ArrayFire.jl documentation)